# Content Security Policy Next Js 13 App Dir NextAuth Middleware Edit: Fixed it partially

Tags: next.js, middleware, content-security-policy, framer-motion

I'm have conflicts with the matcher in Middleware.

```
const cspHeader = `
frame-ancestors 'none';
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
script-src 'self'
```

`
.replace(/\n/g, "")
.trim();
const response = NextResponse.next();
response.headers.set("Content-Security-Policy", cspHeader);

Now, `export const config = { matcher: [ "/home", "/settings", "/settings/personalInformation", "/settings/medicalInformation", "/settings/security", "/cutOffPeriod", ], };`

This matcher is used to put the pages I want to protect with NextAuth, but this also affects the pages due to the csp set. I don't have any script, I use Framer Motion but I don't get why the Nav Menu made with this wouldn't open.

---

### Error in client console

"Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash (''), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

On line 1

I don't have scripts anywhere. OneSignal which is planned to be used is commented. So there might be something with FramerMotion idk.

Clearly I can put 'unsafe-inline' but wouldnt enable scripts that are not mine? Im very new to this so thats why I'm a bit clueless.

---

### Edit:

```
    const nonce = Buffer.from(crypto.randomUUID()).toString("base64");
    const cspHeader = `
    frame-ancestors 'none';
    script-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' 'strict-dynamic';
  `
      .replace(/\n/g, "")
      .trim();
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
    requestHeaders.set("x-nonce", nonce);
    requestHeaders.set("Content-Security-Policy", cspHeader);
    const response = NextResponse.next({
      request: { headers: requestHeaders },
    });
    response.headers.set("Content-Security-Policy", cspHeader);
```

This put the nonce on all scripts, but Im still fighting with a single one.

Content Security Policy of your site blocks the use of 'eval' in JavaScript`
The Content Security Policy (CSP) prevents the evaluation of arbitrary strings as JavaScript to make it more difficult for an attacker to inject unathorized code on your site.

main-app.js?v=1700109450773:1535    script-src  blocked

This sends me to an eval **webpack_require**.ts and I don't know how to fix it.

---

### Edit 2:

So to fix that one I had to do 'unsafe-eval' for script-src in development. But in prod, I can use it without the 'unsafe-eval' so I think that this is the fix?